# Method "stimulate" is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead

Tags: reactjs, simulation, enzyme

I am currently learning Angular.js to develop a meet events application and I need to get this Event.test.js file to work. I'm struggling because I keep getting this error, and I can't figure out why. I've provided screenshots of the error my event.test.js code, and my event.js. Any help is greatly appreciated thank you.

[Event.test.js]

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Event from '../Event'; // <-- Update file path to Event module

describe('<Event /> component', () => {
    const event = {
        summary: 'Test event',
        start: {
            dateTime: '2023-05-08T14:30:00',
        },
        location: 'Test location',
        description: 'Test description',
        organizer: {
            email: 'test@example.com',
        },
    };

    it('should render event details when show details button is clicked', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<Event event={event} />);
        expect(wrapper.find('.event-details').length).toEqual(0);
        wrapper.find('.show-details-button').simulate('click');
        expect(wrapper.find('.event-details').length).toEqual(1);
        expect(wrapper.find('.event-summary').text()).toEqual(event.summary);
        expect(wrapper.find('.event-location').text()).toEqual(event.location);
        expect(wrapper.find('.event-description').text()).toEqual(event.description);
        expect(wrapper.find('.event-organizer').text()).toEqual(event.organizer.email);
    });
});
```

```
[Developer Command Prompt]
 ● <Event /> component › should render event details when show details button is clicked

    Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.

      19 |         const wrapper = shallow(<Event event={event} />);
      20 |         expect(wrapper.find('.event-details').length).toEqual(0);
    > 21 |         wrapper.find('.show-details-button').simulate('click');
         |                                              ^
      22 |         expect(wrapper.find('.event-details').length).toEqual(1);
      23 |         expect(wrapper.find('.event-summary').text()).toEqual(event.summary);
      24 |         expect(wrapper.find('.event-location').text()).toEqual(event.location);

      at ShallowWrapper.single (node_modules/enzyme/src/ShallowWrapper.js:1652:13)
      at ShallowWrapper.simulate (node_modules/enzyme/src/ShallowWrapper.js:1133:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/__tests__/Event.test.js:21:46)
```

[Event.js]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Event extends Component {
    render() {
        return <div></div>;
    }

    state = {
        showDetails: false,
    }

    handleShowDetails = () => {
        this.setState({ showDetails: !this.state.showDetails });
    }

    render() {
        const { event } = this.props;
        const { showDetails } = this.state;

        return (
            <div className="event">
                <div className="event-summary">
                    <h1 className="event-title">{event.summary}</h1>
                    <p className="event-location">{event.location}</p>
                    <p className="event-date">{event.start.dateTime}</p>
                </div>
                {showDetails && (
                    <div className="event-details">
                        <h2>About event:</h2>
                        <p>{event.description}</p>
                        <a href={event.htmlLink} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
                            See details on Google Calendar
                        </a>
                    </div>
                )}
                <button className="details-btn" onClick={this.handleShowDetails}>
                    {showDetails ? 'Hide details' : 'Show details'}
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Event;
```

I've tried to track back what data I've been passing through with each function. I was able to fix the error of my test where my Test suite failed to run due to it not containing a test. This current error is the newest of the problems.

Comment: This doesn't look like AngularJS, or even Angular. That looks like React.

Comment: Interesting, this course that I'm going through is calling this Angular. Do you have any suggestions that might still help?

Comment: your markup doesn't have a button with the class `.show-details-button`.  it seems to have a `details-btn`, though....